# Binding an image to ASPxBinaryImage in EditFormLayout

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have the following GridView

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="AnagPSGrid" runat="server" Width="100%" KeyFieldName="Id" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnEditFormLayoutCreated="AnagPSGrid_EditFormLayoutCreated">

    <Columns>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Id" Visible="false" />
        <dx:GridViewDataBinaryImageColumn FieldName="Image"/>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Description" />
    </Columns>

    <EditFormLayoutProperties AlignItemCaptionsInAllGroups="true">
        <Items>
            <dx:GridViewLayoutGroup Caption="Anagrafica Prodotto/Servizio" ColumnCount="3" GroupBoxStyle-Caption-Font-Bold="true">
                <GridSettings StretchLastItem="true" ChangeCaptionLocationAtWidth="660">
                    <Breakpoints>
                        <dx:LayoutBreakpoint MaxWidth="500" ColumnCount="1" Name="S" />
                        <dx:LayoutBreakpoint MaxWidth="800" ColumnCount="2" Name="M" />
                    </Breakpoints>
                </GridSettings>
                <Items>

                    <dx:GridViewColumnLayoutItem ShowCaption="False" VerticalAlign="Middle" ColumnName="Image" />
                    <dx:GridViewColumnLayoutItem VerticalAlign="Middle" ColumnName="Description"/>

                </Items>
            </dx:GridViewLayoutGroup>
            <dx:EditModeCommandLayoutItem HorizontalAlign="Right" Paddings-PaddingBottom="0" />
        </Items>
    </EditFormLayoutProperties>
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

And I bind to the GridView a DataSource which contains in the field "Image" a path in which the image is stored.

I'd like to show in EditForm of the GridView the image, so I did this:

```
protected void AnagPSGrid_EditFormLayoutCreated(object sender, ASPxGridViewEditFormLayoutEventArgs e)
        {
            string imagePath = ; // Getting the imagePath
            if (imagePath != null && File.Exists(imagePath))
            {
                Image.ContentBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath);
            }
        }
```

But nothing happens. I think it is due to onInit/onLoad events which bind again the path (instead of the bytes) to the image. How to overcome this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of image control are you using here? This code:

```
image.ContentBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath);
```

No way that code compiles. The web based image control dies NOT have ContentBytes????

You can do it this way:

say we have this markup - a button and a image control - real plane jane:

```
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" />

         <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" 
                    style="height:50%" />
```

Now, code behind to load up the image can be this:

```
       // web based path + url
        string iURL = @"~/Content/Fighters/f35.jpg";
        Image2.ImageUrl = iURL;
```

but, if you have a internal NON web based file/url - perhaps even a file path that is not even part of the web site. The you can use a "plane name" windows file path name.

eg this:

```
        string iURL = @"~/Content/Fighters/f35.jpg";

        // raw file path on disk drive
        string fURL = Server.MapPath(iURL);
        byte[] fBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fURL);
        Image2.ImageUrl = "Data:Image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(fBytes);
```

So you can read the file as binary and pump it out to the web page. But you have to convert it to base 64 encoding - the browser can't accept raw binary data for a file.